# Keyboard must be press hard on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) running OS X El Captain and something unusual is happening to me when using my own account, keys must be pressed really hard to work, however on the other hand, when I'm using the  Guest account, everything works okay!

Do you know what can be the problem? What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any keyboard helper applications or such installed? Did you check your keyboard settings in System Preferences?

Comment: Are you sure it must be pressed harder... not just longer?

Answer (score 1):

Check that Slow Keys isn't enabled in System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, I download few programs just the days before, and I think was some kind of virus, at the monitor of activities, I force to quit few programs and after that I can type my user, ant the other hands my macbook pro was sending files and very high temperature, now is ok, but in a few minutes I will reset it. lets see is I can start it up well.
thanks.